# Cannot compile Linux Kernel v4.14 on Debian Wheezy x86

Tags: linux, compiler-errors

When compiling Linux v4.14 (e.g. v4.14.10) on Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy) it stops with the following error message:

```
./system/buildroot-2017.08.x/output/host/usr/bin/x86_64-buildroot-linux-uclibc-ld \
      -m elf_x86_64 -r -o vmlinux.o --whole-archive built-in.o \
      --no-whole-archive --start-group lib/lib.a arch/x86/lib/lib.a \
      --end-group
built-in.o: member arch/x86/kernel/head_64.o in archive is not an object
```

On Kernel v4.13 the compilation works fine.

Answer (score 1):

`Git bisect` stops at commit `b40a923903d`:

```
b40a923903d0a535676b8d7b22bfe17260c3d35a is the first bad commit
commit b40a923903d0a535676b8d7b22bfe17260c3d35a
Author: Josh Poimboeuf <jpoimboe@redhat.com>
Date:   Fri Oct 13 15:02:01 2017 -0500

    x86/unwind: Make CONFIG_UNWINDER_ORC=y the default in kconfig for 64-bit

    commit fc72ae40e30327aa24eb88a24b9c7058f938bd36 upstream.

    The ORC unwinder has been stable in testing so far.  Give it much wider
    testing by making it the default in kconfig for x86_64.  It's not yet
    supported for 32-bit, so leave frame pointers as the default there.

    Suggested-by: Ingo Molnar <mingo@kernel.org>
    Signed-off-by: Josh Poimboeuf <jpoimboe@redhat.com>
    Cc: Linus Torvalds <torvalds@linux-foundation.org>
    Cc: Peter Zijlstra <peterz@infradead.org>
    Cc: Thomas Gleixner <tglx@linutronix.de>
    Link: http://lkml.kernel.org/r/9b1237bbe7244ed9cdf8db2dcb1253e37e1c341e.1507924831.git.jpoimboe@redhat.com
    Signed-off-by: Ingo Molnar <mingo@kernel.org>
    Signed-off-by: Greg Kroah-Hartman <gregkh@linuxfoundation.org>
```

Disabling `CONFIG_UNWINDER_ORC` fixes the compilation on Debian Wheezy.